# Spring MVC - Implement aerospike session

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aerospike

I want to implement *aerospike* on my Spring MVC website to cache user sessions.

I could implement **Redis** caching, but it as it does not support distributed cache, I want to start to use *aerospike*, but I cannot find any lib or examples on how to implement Spring Session in *aerospike*, allowing me to turn off one of my machines and keep all active users still logged in.

The closest I could get to any implementation was this github repository, but it seems it was abandoned:

https://github.com/vlad-aleksandrov/spring-session-aerospike

This was the tutorial I've followed to implement User Session with redis:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession.html

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-aerospike - this is the project mentioned on the [Spring Data homepage](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/).

Comment: Cool, I noticed that project on the homepage but it doesn't handle the httprequests for spring session :( Unfortunately storing simple objects/data is way easier than handling user sessions

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Aerospike play plugin](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-play-plugins). At the heart of it is the session store. The play plugin is a wrapper on top of it. The session store is available as an independent repo under [mvn](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aerospike/aerospike-session-store)/[gradle](http://artifactory.delving.org/artifactory/gradle-libs/com/aerospike/aerospike-session-store/). It is an official one. So, you should be able to report issues and get help. You can reuse the session store component or write your own based on it.